# How to Write a function where the output for both “sum(2,3)” and “sum(2)(3)” will be 5

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can Anybody help me to write this function
 Write a function where the output for both “sum(2,3)” and “sum(2)(3)” will be 5

I think we need to write function using closer!

Comment: function sum(a, b) {
 return (typeof b != 'undefined') ? a + b : function(b){ return a + b;} ;
}

Answer (score 3):

Syntax as follows: `sum(2)(3)` is related with *currying*. It means that you need to return another function inside the main function to get the desired result.

Here's a nice video about *currying* on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iZLP4qOwY8I), from which I've learned a lot.

```js
function sum(a){
  if (arguments.length == 1) {
    return function(b){
      return a + b;
    }
  } else {
    return Object.keys(arguments).reduce((a,b) => arguments[a] + arguments[b]);
  }
}

console.log(sum(2,3));
console.log(sum(2)(3));
```

As [Karl-André Gagnon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2324107/karl-andr%C3%A9-gagnon) proposed, it can be also done with `bind` function.

```js
function sum(a){
  if (arguments.length == 1) {
    return sum.bind(this, a)
  } else {
    return Object.keys(arguments).reduce((a,b) => arguments[a] + arguments[b]);
  }
}

console.log(sum(2,3));
console.log(sum(2)(3));
```

Comment: it this closure function!

Comment: Thinking out of the box here, and better readability IMHO, you could return `return sum.bind( this, a );` instead of a new anonymous function (even if `bind` technically return an anonymous function).

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Would you like to tell me how does it exactly work? That `bind` function. `this` keyword refers to the first arg (2) and `a` refers to the second one (3)?

Comment: Hi Guys,  Can you please explain me this function!                      
 function sum(a){
  if (arguments.length == 1) {
    return sum.bind(this, a)
  } else {
    console.log(Object.keys(arguments).reduce((a,b) => arguments[a] + arguments[b]));  // I dont understand this line.
  }
}

Comment: Or can we achieve this using closure function!

Comment: @Neelam Yes, we can. Using `bind` function is just another way how to solve it.

Comment: @Kinduser When using bind, it return a new function. The first argument of `.bind` is the context (value of `this`). In this case, it could be anything since `sum()` is not using `this`. Just a good practice to use the same this as the callee on recursive function. Every other arguments of `.bind()` will be the future arguments of the bound function when called. Then, arguments passed when calling the bound function will be **after** the argument passed when calling `.bind()`. So `3 === arguments[1]`. Was that clear enough? ;) Kinda hard to explain a native function...

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Thank you. I appreciate it (:

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon *So 3 === arguments[1]* - shouldn't be it `arguments[0]`?

Comment: @Kinduser Nope, `arguments[0] === 2` in this case since the first argument is the second argument of `.bind()`. if bind had 3 arguments, then `3` would be the third argument. Take a look at this, it might be clearer than the example above: https://jsfiddle.net/d3go9vcu/