# How to make function work with sequence calls and with only one call

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I'm trying to make a function work with this two calls:

```
func(1)(2); // 3
func(1, 2); // 3;
```

What i'm trying to do:

```
function func(x, y) {
  return (function(y) {
    return x + y;
  }(y));
}
```

But this won't work at all when i try to call in sequence. Is there other way to achieve that?

```
function add(x, y) {
  if (y) return x + y;
  return function(y) {
    return x + y;
  };
}
```

This would work, but i think it could be a better solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Write a function where the output for both “sum(2,3)” and “sum(2)(3)” will be 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952425/how-to-write-a-function-where-the-output-for-both-sum2-3-and-sum23-wil)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying), here is how you could do it.

```js
function add(a, b){
 if(typeof b !== 'undefined'){
  return a + b;  
 }else{
  return function(c){
   return a + c;
  }
 }
 
 
}


console.log(add(2, 3));

console.log(add(2)(3));
```

Also check this answer [How to Write a function where the output for both “sum(2,3)” and “sum(2)(3)” will be 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42952425/how-to-write-a-function-where-the-output-for-both-sum2-3-and-sum23-wil)

Answer (score 0):

this is no good reason to do that, IMO, you have a function `func(1, 2)`, if you want to `currify` that, just wrapper it with `curry`, if you use `lodash`, you can curry a function with `var curried = _.curry(function)`, that makes your function clean